# How to _reindex elasticsearch data to new mapping (from flat fields to objects)?

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex

I have an old index (elasticsearch index) has more than 20K objects, this index has fields

```
{
    "title": "Test title",
    "title_ar": "عنوان تجريبي",
    "body": "<p>......</p>"
}
```

I want to _reindex them to convert all data to new mapping like this

```
{
    "title_1": {
        "en": "Test title",
        "ar": "عنوان تجريبي"
    },
    "body": "<p>......</p>"
}
```

What is the best elasticsearch pipeline processor to make this conversion available in _reindex API?

Comment: You will not be able to do that without recreating your index, because the `title` field already exists as `text` and you cannot change it to be an `object`

Comment: I create a new index with new mapping, I can name it `title_1` if it is not possible. the most important thing is converting it to object

Comment: Then if you create a rand new index, it's definitely possible and easy to do

Comment: @Val How can I do it?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to simply use the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) to do this:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_index"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.title = [ 'en' : ctx._source.title, 'ar': ctx._source.title_ar]",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

If in your `old_index` index you have this:

```
{
    "title": "Test title",
    "title_ar": "عنوان تجريبي",
    "body": "<p>......</p>"
}
```

In your new index, you'll have this:

```
{
    "title": {
        "en": "Test title",
        "ar": "عنوان تجريبي"
    },
    "body": "<p>......</p>"
}
```

Comment: I get the following error

    ` "script_stack": [
              "ctx._source.title = [ 'en' : ctx._source.title, 'ar': ctx._source.title_ar]",
              "                                                          ^---- HERE"
            ],`

Comment: there is no `.title` field in `ctx._source.title`, but it is a mandatory field

Comment: Not sure I understand your second comment

Comment: I get `ScriptException[runtime error]; nested: NullPointerException;` on the `title_1` in the following statement `"source": "ctx._source.title_1 = ....`

Comment: You don't need to create the `title_1` field since you're creating a new index you can keep `title`

Comment: this is fantastic. +1

Comment: @Val, if I keep it `title` or `title_1` I still get the same error `ScriptException[runtime error]; nested: NullPointerException;`, the error is `_source` is null. I cannot get any field inside it

Comment: Please update your question with the full/exact error you get